# ng-model as value for ng-init input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to figure out on how can I set the value of my input based on the ng-model of my another input, Here is what I did:

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.register = {
      regData: {
        branch: {},
      },
      bloodbankchapters: [
        {_id:'5c014c999cc48c3b0057988b', chapter_name:"AB"},
        {_id:'5c014c999cc48c3b0057988c', chapter_name:"A"},
      ],
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <select ng-model="register.regData.branch" ng-options ="chapter.chapter_name for chapter in register.bloodbankchapters track by chapter._id">
    <option ng-repeat="chapter in register.bloodbankchapters" >{{chapter.chapter_name}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>{{register.regData.branch.chapter_name}}</div>
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="register.regData.branch_name" name="branch_name"  ng-init="register.regData.branch_name='{{register.regData.branch.chapter_name}}'"> 
  
</div>
```

As you can see, my second input literally show `{{register.regData.branch.chapter_name}}` instead of showing `chapter_name`, How can I show the chapter_name in my second input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are slight changes in HTML. You can refer [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/f3r8y246/6/)

```
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <select ng-model="register.regData.branch" ng-options ="chapter.chapter_name for chapter in register.bloodbankchapters" ng-change="register.regData.branch_name=register.regData.branch.chapter_name">
    <option ng-repeat="chapter in register.bloodbankchapters" >{{chapter.chapter_name}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>{{register.regData.branch.chapter_name}}</div>

  <input type="text" ng-model="register.regData.branch_name" name="branch_name"> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need something like this? 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-52l5k7

If you want to reuse your ng-model you should use ng-bind to bind data. 
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-52l5k7)